# Array or ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is an exercise:

Write an algorithm that declares and fills an array of 7 values numerics, bij putting the values to 0.

In Python I have to do this:

```
note = []

for i in range(7):
    note.append(0)

print( note )
```

I have tried below in Java... I am obliged to use an arrayList?

I would like the do with an array empty.

```
int[] notes;

for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
  notes.add(0);
}
```

Comment: Your Java code doesn't even compile

Comment: list in python is not the same as array in java

Comment: you need to tell Java how long the array is, you don't initialize your array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
int[] notes = new int[7];

for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
  notes[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the literal translation of the Python code, but note that in Java, the array already has 0s in it when you create it, so the loop here is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

When declaring your notes array you must initialize it and specify the length of it. If not it will throw a compilation error. Proceed as follows:

```
int[] notes = new int[7]; //Declare the size of the array as 7

for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
  notes[i] = 0; //Iterate the positions of the array via the variable i.
}
```

If you want to use an ArrayList:

```
List<Integer> notes = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //You don't have to define the length.
for(int i = 0; i < 7, i++) {
    notes.add(0);
}
```

Comment: It won't throw a NPE unless you initialise it as `null`. If you don't initialise it, then the code won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do like this.

```
Arrays.fill(notes, -1);// But notes has to be declared.
```

or

```
int[] notes = {0,0,0};
```

Answer (score 2):

For the special case of `int` and a desired value of `0`, you don't even have to write out the loop assignment. You just need this:

```
int[] notes = new int[7];
```

This will create an array of `int`s, each with the Java default value of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an assignment operation.

notes[i] = 0;

Comment: he doesn't initialize the array with a size so this wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Another option - using streams:

```
int[] notes = IntStream.range(0, 7).map(i -> 0).toArray();
```

But if you need exactly 0, you can simply do it like:

```
int[] notes = new int[7]; // but it for 0 only
```